# set header in response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I haven't work with cookies before and currently trying to store data in cookies.This is the response I am getting in console.log()

[image: response in console.log()]

I want to set cookies in header with setHeader(). This is the async function getjwt() using to send data to backend.

```
async function getjwt(req, res) {
  const apiRes= await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: Body,
    }
  );
  console.log(apiRes);
  const data = await apiRes.json();
  console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++");
  console.log(data.access);
  console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++");
  if (apiRes.status === 200) {
    res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", [
      cookie.serialize("access", data.access, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 60 * 30,
        sameSite: "strict",
        path: "/auth/",
      }),
      cookie.serialize("refresh", data.refresh, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
        sameSite: "strict",
        path: "/auth/",
      }),
    ]);
  } else {
    return res.status(apiRes.status).json({
      error: "Authentication failed",
    });
  }
}
```

ERROR-

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res is undefined
```

how can I set Header in response.

Comment: What is `res` that you take in `getjwt`?

Comment: can I replace res with apiRes.setHeader() ? . if getjwt() takes nothing as parameter.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: apiRes.setHeader is not a function

Comment: Are you using node.js as server?

Comment: No, django as backend

Comment: when you fetch something, the api gives back  data, that is it  you can't change the header of the response on client side. that needs to be done on the server. if you wanna set a cookie on the client check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie